# Status expected:<200> but was:<404> in JUnit4 spring boot 2 test

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit4

I am writing to you because I have created a simple controller class in Spring Boot with a related test but when I start the test, I get the error:
" Status expected:<200> but was:<404> "

If you need the full stack-trace, here is it:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:59)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals(AssertionErrors.java:122)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.StatusResultMatchers.lambda$matcher$9(StatusResultMatchers.java:627)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:196)
at com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController.testGreetingsController(TestRestController.java:32)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:84)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

My controller class is:

```
package com.xantrix.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class SalutiRestController 
{
    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public String getGreetings()
    {
        return "Saluti, sono il tuo primo web services";
    }
}
```

while the test I run with JUnit4 is:

```
package com.xantrix.webapp;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import com.xantrix.controller.SalutiRestController;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(SalutiRestController.class)
public class TestRestController 
{
     @Autowired
     private MockMvc mvc;

     @Test
     public void testGreetingsController()
              throws Exception 
      {
         mvc.perform(get("/api/test")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$")
                        .value("Saluti, sono il tuo primo web services"))
                .andDo(print());
      }
}
```

If you need to know what console show, the content is:

```
19:13:06.298 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner constructor called with [class com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.308 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
19:13:06.318 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
19:13:06.383 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper]
19:13:06.404 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController], using SpringBootContextLoader
19:13:06.411 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]: class path resource [com/xantrix/webapp/TestRestController-context.xml] does not exist
19:13:06.412 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]: class path resource [com/xantrix/webapp/TestRestControllerContext.groovy] does not exist
19:13:06.412 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
19:13:06.413 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]: TestRestController does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
19:13:06.498 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.577 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [C:\Users\salmu\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.5.1.RELEASE\SalutiWebService\target\classes\com\xantrix\webapp\Application.class]
19:13:06.578 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.xantrix.webapp.Application for test class com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController
19:13:06.583 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]: using defaults.
19:13:06.583 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
19:13:06.596 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition]
19:13:06.597 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Skipping candidate TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener] due to a missing dependency. Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes and their required dependencies available. Offending class: [org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/TransactionAttribute]
19:13:06.597 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@5276d6ee, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@71687585, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@1807f5a7, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1b919693, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@7fb4f2a9, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@4dc27487, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@6a4f1a55, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@7dfd3c81, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@2584b82d, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@7bbc8656, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@6933b6c6]
19:13:06.600 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.601 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.612 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.613 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.614 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.614 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.614 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.614 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.618 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@2ad48653 testClass = TestRestController, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6bb4dd34 testClass = TestRestController, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.xantrix.webapp.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@7d9f158f key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@69997e9d, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@37654521, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@1b1426f4, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@cd7a990c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@efcca322, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@1e1a0406], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
19:13:06.620 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved @ProfileValueSourceConfiguration [null] for test class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.621 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.annotation.ProfileValueUtils - Retrieved ProfileValueSource type [class org.springframework.test.annotation.SystemProfileValueSource] for class [com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController]
19:13:06.625 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener - Performing dependency injection for test context [[DefaultTestContext@2ad48653 testClass = TestRestController, testInstance = com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController@4c2bb6e0, testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@6bb4dd34 testClass = TestRestController, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.xantrix.webapp.Application}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[[ImportsContextCustomizer@7d9f158f key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@69997e9d, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@37654521, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@1b1426f4, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@cd7a990c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@efcca322, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@1e1a0406], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map[[empty]]]].
19:13:06.757 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=-1}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.5.RELEASE)

2020-03-17 19:13:07.236  INFO 26048 --- [           main] com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController    : Starting TestRestController on DESKTOP-SLP7OIN with PID 26048 (started by salmu in C:\Users\salmu\Documents\workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.5.1.RELEASE\SalutiWebService)
2020-03-17 19:13:07.242  INFO 26048 --- [           main] com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-03-17 19:13:08.370  INFO 26048 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-17 19:13:08.693  INFO 26048 --- [           main] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2020-03-17 19:13:08.693  INFO 26048 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2020-03-17 19:13:08.710  INFO 26048 --- [           main] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 17 ms
2020-03-17 19:13:08.747  INFO 26048 --- [           main] com.xantrix.webapp.TestRestController    : Started TestRestController in 1.973 seconds (JVM running for 3.061)

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /api/test
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 404
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Vary:"Origin", "Access-Control-Request-Method", "Access-Control-Request-Headers"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
2020-03-17 19:13:09.151  INFO 26048 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
```

I am taking my first steps in this area of ​​programming, so the reason for this mistake is not very clear to me.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: can you just rename test package  `com.xantrix.webapp` to `com.xantrix.controller` and try

Comment: Hi, thank you a lot for replying. I did what you said and I'm now getting: " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration"

Comment: you mean issue solved?

Comment: Yes, Now I don't get java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404> but i get " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration"

Comment: I've inserted @ContextConfiguration(classes={SalutiRestController.class}) in the Test class and now everything is working well. Thank you a lot ^^